# ASP.NET call onclick function with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my code a user can like a post when they click on the following code:

```
<li><a href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="LikePost" class="icon fa-heart"><%# Eval("Likes") %></a></li>
```

This will run the function LikePost in the codebehind:

```
    public void LikePost(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //like post whit given id using a database query
    }
```

but how can I give that function a parameter, because it needs the postid from the post that the user is going to like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an HTML link, use an `asp:LinkButton` which has a `CommandArgument` property.  Something like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton
    ID="LinkButton1"
    Text='<%#Eval("Likes")%>'
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'
    OnCommand="LikePost" 
    CssClass="icon fa-heart"
    runat="server"/>
```

Then in your code-behind the signature takes a `CommandEventArgs`:

```
public void LikePost(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    // e.CommandArgument should contain the desired value
}
```

Comment: I will try this, but this is not containing the class="icon fa-heart", and I need that to show the like button.

Comment: @LesleyPeters: You can add classes to ASP.NET controls with the `CssClass` property.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Is it also possible to add 2 parameters?

Comment: @LesleyPeters: There's a `CommandName` property you might be able to use for that purpose.  Anything more complex may involve serializing a more complex object as the `CommandArgument` and then de-serializing it in the handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I only need 2 parameters so I could use CommandName for the secend parameter :)